# Displaying messages at top of the form in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I want to display messages at top ids "MessageError" and "MessageOK" according to POST results. Example:

```
<p id="MessageError"></p>
<p id="MessageOK"></p>

<form name="Form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="Form">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="" /> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="" />
</form>

<?php
if ( isset ( $POST[ 'Submit' ] ) ) {
  if ( $_POST[ 'test' ] ) {
    // Echo message at "MessageOK
  }
  else {
    // "Echo message at "MessageError"
  }

}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code above your form to print the error message above your form. Also your paragraph tags can be created on the fly, to avoid waste:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST['test'])echo("<p id='MessageOk'>There was an Error</p>");
        else echo("<p id='MessageError'>There was no error</p>");
    }
?>
```

If you are dead set on adding content to pre-created divs using PHP, can I suggest creating an  input using PHP eg:

```
 <?php
        $test = $_POST['test'];
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='test' value='$test' />");
 ?>
```

And then using JavaScript to append data:

```
if(document.getElementById('test').value){
    document.getElementById('MessageOk').innerHTML = 'No Error';
}
else{
    document.getElementById('MessageError').innerHTML = 'Error ??';
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. The reason why I rather don't place it on top is described in comment to rbtux answer.

Comment: Thank you. That will work. I don't see the reason to create a hidden input, though.

Comment: To pass the information between PHP and javascript (Serverside to client side)

Comment: I see. I'll do it with inline javascript. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

move your php code over the form, assign the echo message to a variable and use `<?php echo $variable; ?>` to print the message at the appropriate place...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't do that because when an error is found the script wll **die** and the form will stop displaying. That is why it should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the _ on your post variable.

```
$_POST[]
```